# Is this intended behavior or a bug in datetime timedelta?

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, pytz

```
from datetime import datetime timedelta
import pytz

ppt = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
first = ppt.localize(datetime(2013, 3, 10, 0, 0, 0))
first+=timedelta(hours=2)
first
```

returns `datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)`

It should return `datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 10, 3, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)`

You can workaround this, apparent, bug by doing `astimezone(ppt)` after adding the hours.

So, is this a bug?  Am I doing it wrong?  Or is it intended to have code refresh after adding time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `normalize()` using the timezone object again when doing datetime arithmetic:

```
>>> first
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 10, 2, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PST-1 day, 16:00:00 STD>)
>>> ppt.normalize(first)
datetime.datetime(2013, 3, 10, 3, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Pacific' PDT-1 day, 17:00:00 DST>)
```

As noted [in the docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/):

> In addition, if you perform date arithmetic on local times that cross DST boundaries, the result may be in an incorrect timezone. A `normalize()` method is provided to correct this.

Comment: Hmm guess I missed that part of the doc.  Thanks.